# Trying to display a button element inside of a popover but it is not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I created an element where when you hover over the inbox icon (font-awesome), a popover will appear.  I am trying to display a button on the second row of that popover, but it is not appearing. I was using jquery to get display my html elements.  The title is appearing, but the button is not. I thought I was suppose to wrap my html elements in quotes, but that is not working. If someone can explain to me what  it is I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

This is how it looks currently:

[image]

This is my html.

```
  <div id="ex4">
    <span class="p1 fa-stack fa-2x has-badge" data-count="!">
     <i class="fa fa-inbox"  data-toggle="popover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
 </div>
```

Here is the function I created using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        trigger : 'hover',
        html: true,
        title:'10 days remaining in your trial!', 
        content:'<div class="button"><button>Close<button></div>'
    });   
});
```

Comment: have you forgot to add  closing `</button>`  tag in `content` ?

Comment: I did add, but it is not working.  I tested it it by using p tags, h1 tags and it's working fine.  Not sure why the button is not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when you are using `content:'<div class="button"><button>Close<button></div>'` it treated it as text rather than an html element. I tried following code and its seems to work.

Another observation is that when you are trying to bind popup with hover event, as soon as you leave the icon the popup will close. So you may have to bind it with click event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="ex4">
    <span class="p1 fa-stack fa-2x has-badge" data-count="!">
     <i class="fa fa-inbox"  data-toggle="popover" aria-hidden="true">[icon]</i>
    </span>
 </div>
 
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        title:'10 days remaining in your trial!',
        content: function () {
             return $("<div class='button'><button>Close</button></div>");
        }
    });   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this as reference.
It will surely help you.
this popover shows on page load

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('modalOverlay').style.display = 'none'
  };
};
```

```css
body {
        background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492518757308-3eaa20dbb0e2');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    #modalOverlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            z-index: 99999;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
    }
.modalPopup {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background: #fff;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0 0 30px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
.modalContent {padding: 0 2em;}
.headerBar {
        width: 100%;
        background: #edcb04 url(http://cognex.com/gfx/site/bg-global-header.png) repeat-x 0 0;
        margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
.headerBar img {
        margin: 1em .7em;
    }
h1 {
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
p {margin: .75em 0 1.5em;}
.buttonStyle {
        border: transparent;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #6d6d6d;
        color: #eee !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 6px 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%, #1e1e1e 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6d6d6d), color-stop(100%,#1e1e1e));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%,#1e1e1e 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%,#1e1e1e 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%,#1e1e1e 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6d6d6d 0%,#1e1e1e 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6d6d6d', endColorstr='#1e1e1e',GradientType=0 );
    /*  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #999;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #999; */
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .buttonStyle:hover {
        background: #1e1e1e;
        color: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e1e1e 0%, #6d6d6d 100%, #6d6d6d 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e1e1e), color-stop(100%,#6d6d6d), color-stop(100%,#6d6d6d));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e1e1e 0%,#6d6d6d 100%,#6d6d6d 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e1e1e 0%,#6d6d6d 100%,#6d6d6d 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e1e1e 0%,#6d6d6d 100%,#6d6d6d 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e1e1e 0%,#6d6d6d 100%,#6d6d6d 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e1e1e', endColorstr='#6d6d6d',GradientType=0 );
    }
.returnToProfile {text-align: center; margin:3em;}
.returnToProfile a, .returnToProfile a:visited {color: #ddd;}
.returnToProfile a:hover {color: #fff;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modal popup</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Place the JS here or just before the BODY close.
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="modalOverlay">
        <div class="modalPopup">
            <div class="headerBar">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x25/edcb04/333333/?text=LOGO" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="modalContent">
                    <h1>Modal window title here</h1>
                     <p>Modal appears on page load, presents information and is dismissed after the "Close" button is clicked. Styled modal messaging, images and other information here.</p>
                     <button class="buttonStyle" id="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <!--p class="returnToProfile"><a href="https://codepen.io/ptamaro" target="_parent">Return to profile</a></p-->
</body>
</html>
```